# Double integration with infinity bounds and integration by parts

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm unclear about the below double integration solution - which is a probability theory problem to solve for c with joint probability density function. It's been a while since I last took Calculus, so forgive me if it is an obvious question. I don't get why on line 9 for integration by parts $uv=-y^3e^{-y}$ instead of $y^3e^{-y}$ - I am not sure where the negative sign came from. Also, why does the previous parts of the integral ($-y^3e^{-y}, -3y^2e^{-y}, -6ye^{-y}$) evaluated from 0 to infinity resolve to 0 in line 9, 11, 13.

[image: Double Integration]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In line 9, using $u=y^3$ and $dv=e^{-y}$ gives $v=-e^{-y}$. And so, $uv=-y^3e^{-y}$.
2. The reason that $\lim_{y\rightarrow\infty} \dfrac{d y^n}{e^y}=0$ (for a constant $d$ and a positive integer $n$) is by repeated application of the L'Hopital's Rule.
3. Additionally, there seems to be a typo in Line 6. Instead of $2y^3e^{-y}-\dfrac{2y^3}{3}$, we should have $2y^3e^{-y}-\dfrac{2y^3 e^{-y}}{3}$ in the integrand.